# Database design and query optimization/general efficiency when joining 6 tables in mySQL

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, join, query-optimization

I have 6 tables. These are simplified for this example.

```
user_items

ID | user_id | item_name | version
-------------------------------------
1  | 123     | test      | 1

data

ID | name | version | info
----------------------------
1  | test | 1       | info

data_emails

ID | name | version | email_id
------------------------
1  | test | 1       | 1
2  | test | 1       | 2

emails

ID | email
-------------------
1  | email@address.com
2  | second@email.com

data_ips

ID | name | version | ip_id
----------------------------
1  | test | 1       | 1
2  | test | 1       | 2

ips

ID | ip
--------
1  | 1.2.3.4
2  | 2.3.4.5
```

What I am looking to achieve is the following.

The user (123) has the item with name 'test'. This is the basic information we need for a given entry.

There is data in our 'data' table and the current version is 1 as such the version in our user_items table is also 1. The two tables are linked together by the name and version. The setup is like this as a user could have an item for which we dont have data, likewise there could be an item for which we have data but no user owns..

For each item there are also 0 or more emails and ips associated. These can be the same for many items so rather than duplicate the actual email varchar over and over we have the data_emails and data_ips tables which link to the emails and ips table respectively based on the email_id/ip_id and the respective ID columns.

The emails and ips are associated with the data version again through the item name and version number.

**My first query is is this a good/well optimized database setup?**

My next query and my main question is joining this complex data structure.

What i had was:

```
PHP
- get all the user items
- loop through them and get the most recent data entry (if any)
- if there is one get the respective emails
- get the respective ips
```

Does that count as 3 queries or essentially infinite depending on the number of user items?

I was made to believe that the above was inefficient and as such I wanted to condense my setup into using one query to get the same data.

I have achieved that with the following code

```
SELECT user_items.name,GROUP_CONCAT( emails.email SEPARATOR ',' ) as emails, x.ip

FROM user_items

JOIN data AS data ON (data.name = user_items.name AND data.version = user_items.version)

LEFT JOIN data_emails AS data_emails ON (data_emails.name = user_items.name AND data_emails.version = user_items.version)

LEFT JOIN emails AS emails ON (data_emails.email_id = emails.ID)

LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT name,version,GROUP_CONCAT( the_ips.ip SEPARATOR ',' ) as ip FROM data_ips
     LEFT JOIN ips as the_ips ON data_ips.ip_id = the_ips.ID  ) 
     x ON (x.name = data.name AND x.version = user_items.version)
```

I have done loads of reading to get to this point and worked tirelessly to get here.
This works as I require -  this question seeks to clarify what are the benefits of using this instead?

I have had to use a subquery (I believe?) to get the ips as previously it was multiplying results (I believe based on the complex joins). How this subquery works I suppose is my main confusion.

**Summary of questions.**

-Is my database setup well setup for my usage? Any improvements would be appreciated. And any useful resources to help me expand my knowledge would be great.

-How does the subquery in my sql actually work - what is the query doing?

-Am i correct to keep using left joins - I want to return the user item, and null values if applicable to the right.

-Am I essentially replacing a potentially infinite number of queries with 2? Does this make a REAL difference? Can the above be improved?

-Given that when i update a version of an item in my data table i know have to update the version in the user_items table, I now have a few more update queries to do. Is the tradeoff off of this setup in practice worthwhile?

Thanks to anyone who contributes to helping me get a better grasp of this !!

Answer (score 0):

Given your data layout, and your objective, the query is correct. If you've only got a small amount of data it shouldn't be a performance problem - that will change quickly as the amount of data grows. However when you ave a large amount of data there are very few circumstances where you should *ever* see all your data in one go, implying that the results will be filtered in some way. Exactly how they are filtered has a huge impact on the structure of the query.

> How does the subquery in my sql actually work

Currently it doesn't work properly - there is no GROUP BY

> Is the tradeoff off of this setup in practice worthwhile?

No - it implies that your schema is too normalized.

Comment: Could you expand a little on the latter two points. I am asking how the subquery works? It gives me the result I want - as such what is qrong with it? As for the setup, are you saying I should simply use multiple queries and PHP loops?

Comment: you have a `group_concat` but no group defined, you need a `group by` clause for  that.

Comment: try an `EXPLAIN` on your query and post the result.

Comment: I would post the results of EXPLAIN but i have massively simplified my tables for this question. Do I need a group_by for both the main query and the sub query? I understand the implication that I can improve the query by using indexes etc in the database tables. How about my other questions? Thanks